# Can chromecast run Youtube Javascript player API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, chromecast

As title, my web app is using Youtube javascript player API (chromeless player).
Is it possible to modify it to be a receiver app and running on chromecast??

Thanks!

Kevin Kuei

Comment: http://semanticmedia.byu.edu/2013/08/youtube-apis-and-googles-new-chromecast.html seems related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per understanding, No. It shouldn't work , as it doesnt support flash. IFrame API should work though.